# Multiple Entities need an address in database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-attribute-value

I have two entities **customers** and **stores** and they both need **adresses** should i do different adresses tables for each entity or use one for both with 2 different foreign keys but the the 2nd case i will probably have a lot of **null** values in my table since only one of both will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields of the address table are similar for each entity I would use one address table with foreign keys.

If there are lots of specifics fields for customers and stores in your address then i would use 1 table for each...